# How to change the position of an element in CSS without changing the HTML structure?

Tags: html, css

I have this example:

```css
.icon-test {
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
}

.header-content {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

.top-menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-style: initial;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="header">
  <div class="panel-wrapper">
    <input type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
      <ul class="top-menu">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
    <span>Here you need to insert the input without changing the HTML structure</span>
    <i class="icon-test"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is move the `<input>` element next to the menu without changing the HTML structure.

I tried to do it with `display:flex` but I didn't succeed.

Is this possible or is it necessary to change the structure?

Comment: if you give display: flex; to .header -> you can use order. you must have a parent that wraps all your children and displayed as flex of course.

Comment: further reading on ordering flex items https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

Comment: yes, can this be done? do you have an example somewhere please?

Comment: this can be done as long as your items are wrapped with a parent component. in this case, since your input is not contained in the menu,  apply flex using the outermost parent -> which is .header

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I position the elements in 2 rows in this case? display:flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70350526/how-can-i-position-the-elements-in-2-rows-in-this-case-displayflex)

Answer (score 0):

add `display: inline-block` to .panel-wrapper and .header-content

Comment: can you please edit my example? I tried to do as you say but I failed.

He must be before the icon, not after

Answer (score 0):

add `float: right` to .panel-wrapper

```css
.icon-test {
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
}
.panel-wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right
}
.header-content {
  display:inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

.top-menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-style: initial;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="header">
  <div class="panel-wrapper">
    <input type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
      <ul class="top-menu">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
    <span>Here you need to insert the input without changing the HTML structure</span>
    <i class="icon-test"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```