# How can I position the elements in 2 rows in this case? display:flex

Tags: html, css

Here is an example:

[link](https://codepen.io/dcrysty23/pen/wvrgyze)

**CODE HTML:**

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
}

.list-icon {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://cdn1.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/36/80/exercise-stress-test-logo-icon-design-vector-15613680.jpg" width="100px" height="70px" />
  </div>
  <div class="search">
    <input value="search" />
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Element 1</li>
      <li>Element 2</li>
      <li>Element 3</li>
      <li>Element 4</li>
      <li>Element 5</li>
      <li>Element 6</li>
      <li>Element 7</li>
      <li>Element 8</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-icon">
    <i class="fas fa-info"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-adjust"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is align the menu and the 2 icons in line with the logo (under search) without changing the html structure.

Is it possible to do this with flex display or is it necessary to modify the whole structure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you will have to change the HTML structure.

Comment: Not recommended yet you may use `ms-flex-order` or/and `order` css properties. Suppose `.menu{ ms-flex-order: 2; order: 2; }` while `ms-flex-order: 1; order: 1;` added to both `.list-icon` and `.search` classes. 
See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Answer (score 0):

You may use [order css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order), as stated

> The order CSS property sets the order to lay out an item in a flex or grid container. Items in a container are sorted by ascending order value and then by their source code order.

```css
 ul li {
          list-style-type: none;
          display: inline-block;
        }

        .header {
          max-width: 900px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .search {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          width: calc(100% - 120px);
          ms-flex-order: 1;
          order: 1;
        }

        .list-icon {
          display: flex;
          position: relative;
          margin-left: 20px;
          ms-flex-order: 1;
          order: 1;
        }

      .menu{
          ms-flex-order: 2;
          order: 2;
       }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://cdn1.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/36/80/exercise-stress-test-logo-icon-design-vector-15613680.jpg" width="100px" height="70px" />
  </div>
  <div class="search">
    <input value="search"/>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Element 1</li>
      <li>Element 2</li>
      <li>Element 3</li>
      <li>Element 4</li>
      <li>Element 5</li>
      <li>Element 6</li>
      <li>Element 7</li>
      <li>Element 8</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-adjust"></i>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```